# Generate UML class diagrams from C++ code

Tags: c++, uml, reverse-engineering

Does anyone know of a standalone software (or plugin for Visual Studio) that can generate UML class diagrams from C++ code?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [DoxyGen](http://www.doxygen.nl).

It is widely used in industry . If you add specially formatted comments  to your code, it can generate some very useful documentation. in fact the first thing I do on every new contract is to run the code through Doxygen.

In fact, even without the comments, it still gives a great deal of information, such as call trees, class diagrams and the like.

Read about its diagrams [here](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/diagrams.html)

And read the S.O question [How to use doxygen to create UML class diagrams from C++ source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755913/how-to-use-doxygen-to-create-uml-class-diagrams-from-c-source)

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio 2017 (Community Edition), and later versions, have a Class Designer component for generating class diagrams. Follow the setup instructions by Microsoft in this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/class-designer/how-to-add-class-diagrams-to-projects?view=vs-2019) for installing the Class Designer component.

Once installed, open your Visual Studio project, right-click on a header file and select the "View Class Diagram" option.

**Caveat:** The Class Designer feature only works with Visual Studio project files (i.e. `*.vcxproj`). You won't be able to use this feature if you have a CMake project. Check [this post](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/cmake-projects-wont-display-class-view-data/1356204#T-N1357302) on Visual Studio's developer community for further info.

Comment: Deespite having the currently most upvoted comment, I believe this to be the simplest solution. Doxygen is excelleant, and I highly recommend using it (fully), but this answers OP's quiestion, cheap & cheerfuly. Good answer

Answer (score 2):

This is *not exactly* UML (but neither are the class diagrams in VS), but comparable and it provides so much more: [SourceTrail](https://www.sourcetrail.com).

The application is FLOSS and [hosted over on GitHub](https://github.com/CoatiSoftware/Sourcetrail).

Comment: I use [Understand](https://www.scitools.com/) at work, and searched for a loooong time for a gratis alternative. I was overjoyed when I found SourceTrail. This gets my vote